# Visual Studio 2008 Intellisense Priority Settings

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, intellisense

Is there someway to get VS 2008 intellisense to default to Properties over Classes in a name collision?

*Example:*

Within my scope I have a property `Foo`, but I'm also *using* a class `Foo`. When writing code, if I start to type <kbd>F</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd>, VS2008 intellisense will think I mean the class `Foo`. I want it to think I mean the property `Foo` instead.

Comment: 100 bounty for most annoying problem of my day.  Because the priority is in the wrong order when I have a property with the same name as the class, when I type it and hit `.` it **auto-completes with the fully-qualified name of the class**, meaning I *can't* use the property anymore without deleting all that sh*t VS just added (by hitting ctrl+z, then backspace, then `.` again).  This behavior occurs even after removing `.` from the "committed after pressing the following characters" option box.  This problem admittedly sounds minor, until it happens to you 200 times in one day.

Comment: I'll award the bounty to anyone who knows of a way to stop that specific problem (not necessarily by changing the priority of the categories).

Comment: (in C#) You can alias the class: `using FooClass = Foo;`  If you are within an instance member, you can refer to the Foo property as `this.Foo`.  At class-level scope, it has to be fully-qualified. This is why Microsoft's design guidelines suggest that you don't name properties or methods the same as their return type.

Comment: @Jim: This is *why?*  Because intellisense makes a bad choice of default?

Comment: It may seem contrived, but assume you have the following (poorly named) namespace hierarchy: `A.B.C.A` (this could happen if your company name is a fairly common word like *Red*).  If you wanted intellisense to access some enum at the top-level namespace from within class `A`, in your desired property-up search, the only way would be to type `global::A.MyEnum`.  Most devs don't know this construct and is would be an annoyance to those who 1) don't use code assist or 2) don't use Visual Studio

Comment: Also, I realize that is a class-based example.  But, the same could go for defining a property `public A A {get;set}` in class `D`.

Comment: @Jim: Well, no, they could type `A`, then use the down-arrow key to select the namespace rather than the property, then type the `.`.  The way it is now, that's exactly what I have to do, but for properties; and since referencing a property inside a class is *significantly* more common than referencing a namespace, the fact that namespace is the default can only be considered a mistake.

Comment: I understand what you're saying.  But, breaking the top-down approach to type discovery for code assist depending on scope could become confusing. Have you tried any productivity plugins like CodeRush or Resharper which might override this default in intellisense?  For instance, Resharper has a smart code completion option (CTRL+SHIFT+SPACE).

Comment: @Jim: I use Resharper, but it does not help this problem.  The problem is that VS adds code as a result of me simply typing exactly what I want on the screen, which is clearly not what I want.  I don't understand why the intellisense selection is committed when I hit `.`, even if I have autocomplete disabled!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately no this is not possible.  Customization of the priority of value categories like classes / properties is not supported

Answer (score 1):

There is no possibility in VS2010 and not even in ReSharper 5.0 to deal with this issue. It won't be a feature of ReSharper 6.0 as well, according to JetBrains. I use a different name for the property, when it starts making me aggressive and refactor it after I've done most of the work.

**Update:**

I reported the issue to JetBrains some time ago and I just got an eMail that the feature has been added and will be available in Release 6.1. So good news for ReSharper users on this one!

http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-273067?projectKey=RSRP

Comment: +1 for suggesting the dreaded refactor.  I would avoid using the same name on a Property and Class in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking the exact same thing today.

While the functionality is not in vanilla VS, it is quite possible to modify some code to add this functionality. For example, the XAML Presenter, probably named after the presenter component that you have to modify does something similiar.[XAML Presenter](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2010/03/21/visual-studio-2010-xaml-editor-intellisense-presenter-extension/http://)

It narrows by namespace and sorts by attribute type. Basically, I'm just gonna take the list the Intellisense Completion Source gives and sort the list.  Sounds simple enough.

More challenging is implementing the UI controls. I hate designing UI controls . . .

Edit:

However, I don't forsee a way to do this without breaking Resharper's Intelllisense features.

Answer (score 0):

Use VS 2010, I suppose? I can't see which situation would make VS put classes over properties, though.